# Android best practises: Loading stuff in background and storing results acceptable from multiple activities?

Tags: android, multithreading, background

I am currently developing a application which is capable of locating nearby bus and train stops and display departure boards for the users.
I have a Activity, let us call it Activity1 that displays the 20 nearest stops.
When one of these are clicked, Activity2 is opened and the departure-board is loaded and shown.

In both cases, I am using `AsyncTasks` for data retrieval and `parsing` in background.
What I however would like to do is to load some of the departure boards in the background while showing the nearest stops. These would then be available as soon as the user decides to see one.

So I would like some kind of mechanism (`Thread` or `Service`) that runs parallel with the `UI Thread` and loads these data. The problem is that this mechanism should be accessibly from both the activities. What is the best approach to achieve this?

I thought about creating a static class `SideLoader` with a `Runnable` object and maybe a public list of loaded departure boards that is updated contentiously when this `Runnable` object are executed. Is this seam like a good practice or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also look at the following video from the Google I/O conference on doing REST queries asynchronously and storing the data locally for use.  Excellent description of best practices that you may learn a lot from.  Talks about services, asynctask, contentproviders, and more:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

And to expound on that thought - You might use a ContentProvider to access the information stored in a SQLLite database on the device.  Use a service to fetch the data online and store it in the database through the contentprovider.  Your activities access the contentprovider to retrieve the data.

Comment: That's a great video and I've watched it like 3-4 times, but I still struggle to implement the described behavior. Are you aware of any samples or open-source implementations of the patterns mentioned in the video?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at building an Android Service to manage your background tasks. Each activity could bind to the service and communicate with it as needed.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Hi. It was my understanding (also from the documentation) that it is _only_ good practice to use a service when a task has to be performed when the UI of an application is not visible. But I will give it a try. Thanks